# Unable to inject $location service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

This code gives me `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scope, $locationProvider <- $scope, $location`.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);

app.controller('Signup', ['$scope, $location', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.checkEmailValid = function(){
        //TODO make a decision about whether to go somewhere, if true do this:
        $location.path('/view2');
    };
}]);
```

Am I missing something about how to inject the location service? 
I haven't configured $locationProvider, but doing so doesn't seem to help.

Comment: a Plunkr or JSFiddle?

Comment: @Mik378 whoops let me get right on that...

Comment: you just have a missing quote: `app.controller('Signup', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location)`

Comment: @Sebastian Thank you very much, that was driving me mad!

Comment: By the way, your `app` variable is useless. You could (should) do like this: `angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])`   (on the next line)`.controller(....`

Comment: @Mik378 ah ok I'll change it. Why is that better?

Comment: @KnewB Reason why it's better is very well explained at this page: http://books.google.fr/books?id=mZXjwz5X08EC&pg=PT126&lpg=PT126&dq=different+syntax+for+registering+provider+mastering+angular&source=bl&ots=T5yXNRT8XW&sig=TONlEMqqwFrv_imlq_VIPaBBg68&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nYtyU4G8OMSb0QXvqoHwDQ&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=different%20syntax%20for%20registering%20provider%20mastering%20angular&f=false ;)

Comment: @Mik378 perhaps I misunderstand but my `app` variable is declared using `var` so it won't end up being global (which seems to be the main argument against the pattern I used). Is the point of the better pattern to guard against the possibility of forgetting `var`?

Comment: A simple unexpected closure could corrupt the `var`. It's written on the page I sent.

Comment: @Mik378 it says something like that but doesn't explain it. (I thought I understood about var, function scope and globals.) A topic for a separate question.

Comment: @KnewB The variable might be unexpectedly returned to another context and causing potential bad mutations. When you don't use variables, you have a total isolated code and 0 risks. And it's also cleaner, since less words: not redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the quotes around $scope and $location :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);

app.controller('Signup', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.checkEmailValid = function(){
        //TODO make a decision about whether to go somewhere, if true do this:
        $location.path('/view2');
    };
}]);
```

This should to the trick !

Answer (score 1):

Try simpler form (without array form - probably missing quote is your problem):

```
app.controller('Signup', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.checkEmailValid = function(){
        //TODO make a decision about whether to go somewhere, if true do this:
        $location.path('/view2');
    };
});
```

Minification can be solved in build time using ngMin and this form is less error prone and more readable